# Connect localhost from host virtualbox

Tags: laravel, networking, virtualbox

I have a Laravel app in Virtualbox in the localhost aka 127.0.0.1:8000 and I want to connect from my host to the server.

Also, it will be great that anyone with the same network can connect to my localhost.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the host while running the `php artisan serve` command.

For example, your network IP is 192.168.1.2

Then run the command like this

`php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.2`

Hope this will work for you.